# django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.6

I tried to create an instance of a user in python shell using the following commands.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<User: admin>]>
me = User.objects.get(username='rohan')
```

After which I got the following errors. Can someone please help.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 380, in get
        self.model._meta.object_name
    django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have [no User with username rohan](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist). You seems to have a user with username admin though.

```
me = User.objects.get(username='admin')
```

Comment: alright! I am a beginner and this is my first python project. when I use the above command what exactly does it do? Can you please explain.

Comment: [This page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/) explains it better then I ever could. Good luck and please accept the answer that answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

Your user's username is "admin", as seen in the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `User.objects.get()`, mean you want to retrieve an object from you data base. But looking at you code, you don't have an object of `rohan`, so you can't get it.

So, what you can do here is to create it first.

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 0):

when you use:

```
User.objects.get()
```

It means that you know that the get() will return something and in your case it isn't

You probably want to do the following:

```
User.objects.filter(username='rohan')
```

the filter will execute and, if no user with the username rohan is found, it will return an "empty list" without giving you an exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use exception handling:

```
User = get_user_model() 
            
try:
      user = User.objects.get(username = email)
except Exception as e:
      user=None
```